# Failed to create openStack instance

Tags: openstack, saas, openstack-nova, iaas, openstack-glance

[image]
I'm new to open stack , and when I try to create instance it gives me this error:

> [Error : Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts
> available for retrying build failures for instance
> 57100c2f-a290-4165-b4c0-ba2202cfb728.]

Comment: This means that Nova was successful selecting compute hosts for your instance, but none of the hosts was able to launch the virtual machine or connect it to the network. You or the cloud operator have to look for more information in the nova-compute logs. You may also have additional messages on the instance detail screen (just click on the instance link *ubuntuserver* in the screenshot, or run `openstack server show ubuntuserver` as admin).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, in my compute host i can see in the: **journalctl -xfu neutron-linuxbridge-agent**

> Interface eth12 for physical network flat does not exist. Agent terminated!

My linuxbridge agent service was always restarting.

In this case, i was need to create the virtual devices veth file. My solution was:

1. **vim /etc/systemd/network/25-veth-br-vlan-eth12.netdev**

```
[NetDev]
Name=eth12
Kind=veth
[Peer]
Name=br-vlan-veth
```

2. And adding veth config in netplan file: **vim /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml**

```
   ethernets:
       eno1:
         dhcp4: no
         mtu: 1500
       eno2:
         dhcp4: no
         mtu: 1500
       br-vlan-veth: {}
       eth12: {}
```

3. Apply netplan config:

```
netplan apply
```

4. Restart linuxbridge agent service:

```
systemctl restart neutron-linuxbridge-agent
```

PS: I needed to create the veth devices in all hosts using linuxbridge agent, like controller nodes and compute nodes.

If you are using OVS instead linuxbridge, this solution don't make sense to you, but can help someone that use linuxbridge.

Answer (score 0):

Same here..
We managed to deploy OpenStack through [Kolla-Ansible](https://github.com/openstack/kolla-ansible#:%7E:text=The%20Kolla%20Ansible%20is%20a,tools%20for%20operating%20OpenStack%20clouds.)
Unfortunately just cannot deploy an instance through Horizon. keep getting this error about the scheduler

> Message Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts
> available for >retrying build failures for instance
> 3539a5ba-b4f8-4dea-92a0-618e77d3ee93.
>
> Code 500
>
> Details Traceback (most recent call last): File
>
> > "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nova/conductor/manager.py",
> > line 665, in build_instances raise exception.MaxRetriesExceeded(reason=msg)
> > nova.exception.MaxRetriesExceeded: Exceeded maximum number of retries. >Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures
> > for instance >3539a5ba-b4f8-4dea-92a0-618e77d3ee93.
>
> Created Oct. 3, 2021, 7:21 a.m.

But surprisingly the follwoing command seem to work

```
openstack server create \
--image cirros \
--flavor m1.tiny \
--key-name mykey \
--network demo-net \
demo1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and anti-affinity was the problem. I had not enough resources on 2 host servers, totally was enough resources but separate per host no.

/var/log/kolla/nova/nova-conductor.log:2022-10-12 09:10:51.047 18 ERROR nova.scheduler.utils [req-e374e3f1-9c8b-477a-8c21-e84a34adc424 b9b1a508c5ee45ff82dd110fce67c263 b618f643ecc74ee6ab7a92ddcb62fac9 - default default] [instance: 4bcd776a-8848-4d94-a3cf-bc1ef6a72f0e] Error from last host: krpan-node4.iskratel.cloud (node krpan-node4.iskratel.cloud): [u'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', u'  File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2056, in _do_build_and_run_instance\n    filter_properties, request_spec)\n', u'  File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2347, in _build_and_run_instance\n    instance_uuid=instance.uuid, reason=six.text_type(e))\n', u'RescheduledException: Build of instance 4bcd776a-8848-4d94-a3cf-bc1ef6a72f0e was re-scheduled: Build of instance 4bcd776a-8848-4d94-a3cf-bc1ef6a72f0e was re-scheduled: Anti-affinity instance group policy was violated.\n']

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32924626)